# I'm trying to run php artisan migrate inn my Dockerfile but it gives this error

Tags: laravel, migration

i tryed to add mysql server in docker or to run mysql server localy but nothing happend[this the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wejjD.png)

Comment: Can you add more context? The relevant parts of the dockerfile (and docker compose) for instance. Also is the container running for mysql.

Answer (score -1):

please make sure your MySQL service has already up and serve

edited:
if your MySQL service is on separate container, you can't do `php artisan migrate` from Dockerfile.

Comment: That's not accurate. You'd just need to share a network across the containers.